# Taking a block of strings and storing them in an array

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to write a function that takes a block of strings, does something with the strings, and then returns an array with the strings?

```
def collect_string(&block)
   # just toss them into an array and return it
   return ...
end

a = collect_string {
   "string 1"
   "string 2"
   "string 3"
}
```

When I print out what `a` is, I should get

```
["string 1", "string2", "string3"]
```

Now suppose I decided to change my mind and wanted to do something more with the strings first. Maybe I want to remove all of the vowels first, or just grab the first 3 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really **not** what the blocks are for. You're going to make an array of strings anyway, so why not use an array to begin with?

```
def collect_string &block
  v = block.call
  # do something with v
end

# block returning array
a = collect_string {[
   "string 1",
   "string 2",
   "string 3"
]}
```

If you use a block as in your example then it will return only "string 3", the last expression evaluated. Previous strings are lost.

Comment: I was thinking maybe my collect_string method might take a bunch of options for formatting a set of strings, and then I can just pass in the actual strings in a block. I could always just set them all as parameters, but I was looking to see how something like what I wanted would be done.

Comment: @Keikoku you can pass a block, but return an array from it, not raw string literals.

Comment: Passing an array into the block is fine. I'm looking at the Proc docs but I'm not sure how to actually grab the array and do stuff with its elements.

Comment: Thanks! Although I have to pass in an array, I guess it's something that can't be helped.